# Atom ide-php path to PHP 7 folder

Tags: php, ide, homebrew, atom-editor

I installed the new GitHub Atom version 1.21 and want to use ide-php package to get PHP 7 support, autocomplete etc.

Currently it doesn't work out of the box. I installed PHP 7 using homebrew and want to add the path to PHP 7 folder in the input of the package configuration.

Anynone knows what the path is?

I am on macOS Sierra, installed php 7.1.8 with homebrew.

Comment: `brew --prefix php72` (replace `php72` with the formula you want)

Answer (score 1):

I am using mamp with windows and my php folder is like this. don't forget to add 'php.exe' at the end. maybe it can give you an idea

`"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\MAMP\\bin\\php\\php7.4.1\\php.exe"`

edited for xampp, `"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"`

Answer (score 0):

You can find the path of any binary that has been made available via PATH by typing this in your console:

```
which php
```

Which (for me on macOS) returns:

```
/usr/local/bin/php
```

You can also check the version of php by typing this:

```
php -v
```